# Change item value of referenced array in clousure

Tags: f#, sequence

Look, I've got some method where I try to check if value is changed and write it if it is changed but so , I need to remember wich values had changed and here is a problem, I can't set changed flag because I don't know how to cheange ref item and I can't use mutable there.

```
member X.qArchive() = 
    //let mutable rememberer = [for d in db.AlarmDictionaries -> d.ID, false].ToArray() 

    let rememberer = ref ( [for d in db.AlarmDictionaries -> d.ID, false].ToArray() )

    seq {for a in db.ArchiveDescretes do 
            let i = ref 0
            for r in !rememberer do 
                if a.ID = fst r && snd r = false then
                    rememberer.[(!i)] := fst r, true // Error
                    //rememberer.[(!i)] <- fst r, true // Error
                    for c in db.AlarmDictionaries do
                    if (c.ID = a.ID) then
                        yield a.Date, c.Message, a.Value
                i := !i + 1 } |> Array.ofSeq
```

also if you know how can I realize this idea with some better way I will thank you too.

here is my wicked variant :

```
    member X.qArchive() = 
    seq {   let metarememberer = ref ( [for d in db.AlarmDictionaries -> d.ID, false].ToArray() )
            let rememberer = ref ( [for d in db.AlarmDictionaries -> d.ID, false].ToArray() )
            for a in db.ArchiveDescretes do 
                let i = ref 0
                for r in !metarememberer do 
                    if a.ID = fst r && snd r = false then
                        (!metarememberer).[!i] <- fst r, true
                        for c in db.AlarmDictionaries do
                            if c.ID = a.ID && c.Value = a.Value then
                                let j = ref 0
                                for rm in !rememberer do 
                                    if a.ID = fst rm then
                                        (!rememberer).[!j] <- fst rm, a.Value
                                    j := !j + 1
                                yield a.Date, c.Message
                    else
                        let j = ref 0
                        for rm in !rememberer do
                            if a.ID = fst rm && a.Value <> snd rm then
                                (!rememberer).[!j] <- fst rm, a.Value
                                for c in db.AlarmDictionaries do
                                    if c.ID = a.ID && c.Value = a.Value then
                                        yield a.Date, c.Message
                            j := !j + 1
                    i := !i + 1 
        } |> Array.ofSeq
```

**Update :** After all my variant doesn't work. Something wrong here ... I can see same event 2 times, I need to see it only when value is changed so that means I can't see same event 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this one?

```
(!rememberer).[!i] <- fst r, true
```